# Can we use branch prediction along with atomic operations?

Tags: linux-kernel, atomic

I wanted to know whether we can use branch prediction macros (likely/unlikely) along with any atomic operation. Is there any side effect of below statement ?

```c
atomic_t v = ATOMIC_INIT(0);
atomic_inc(&v);
if (unlikely(atomic_read(&v)) == 2) {
  /* Some Operation */
}
```

Comment: "Is there any side effect of below statement?" - What kind of side effects do you expect? Excepts timing, the code using `likely`/`unlikely` will exhibit the **same behavior** as the code without that macros. Whether in your case `unlikely` really gives better timing or not, depends on many many other things. As usual: if unsure of benefits, then do not use these macros.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between using `likely`/`unlikely` on atomic vs non-atomic operations. The purpose of those macros is only to generate code that performs better in the scenario where one of the two branches of a condition is more likely.

So for a "normal" operation you would have for example:

```
if (unlikely(--x))              if (likely(--x))
    do_a();                         do_a();
else                            else
    do_b();                         do_b();


    *decrement x*                   *decrement x*
    jnz not_zero                    jz zero
    call do_b                       call do_a
not_zero:                       zero:
    call do_a                       call do_b
```

While in the case of an atomic operation you would simply have:

```
if (unlikely(atomic_sub_and_test(&x)))   if (likely(atomic_sub_and_test(&x)))
    do_a();                                  do_a();
else                                     else
    do_b();                                  do_b();
                          
                          
    *atomically decrement x*                 *atomically decrement x*
    jnz not_zero                             jz zero
    call do_b                                call do_a
not_zero:                                zero:
    call do_a                                call do_b
```